# c# System.InvalidCastException when casting a char

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a field in DB called member_id_card_search_key (char[2]), in my `Winforms` Application, there is a line of code like this:

```
person.member_id_card_search_key = (char)membersData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["member_id_card_search_key"];
```

when i run the winform app, there is a exception is throw called "System.InvalidCastException", anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about what you want to achieve by casting a char array into a char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you mention, the data type for the column is `char[2]`. You are trying to cast it to a `char`, which is one character. Try casting it to a `string`.

Comment: i have another column (char,1) person.is_representative = (char)membersData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["is_representative"]; , the exception is same

Comment: @hkguile - an array *containing* one character is still a *different thing* from a character itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails because the return type will be a `char[2]` and you are converting implicitly to a char, which is not a valid conversion. try this:

```
person.member_id_card_search_key = (char[])membersData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["member_id_card_search_key"];
```

if `member_id_card_search_key` accepts character array, or else you can try

```
 person.member_id_card_search_key = (char[])membersData.Tables[0].Rows[i]["member_id_card_search_key"][0];
```

To take the first character from the resulting array